# How to pass data to Mongodb using Node.js, websocket and total.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, total.js

I am trying to pass data to Mongodb using Websocket and total.js.
In my `homepage.html` I can get the user input and connect to the server via websocket after clicking the save button.

In `default.js` is my server side code. At this point the app hat got the user input and connected to the server correctly, but how can I save data to mongodb now?

This is my `homepage.html`

```
<br />
<div>
<input type="text" name="message" placeholder="Service" maxlength="200" style="width:500px" />
<button name="send" >Save</div>
</div>
<br />

<script type="text/javascript">
  var socket = null;
  $(document).ready(function() {
    connect();
    $('button').bind('click', function() {

        if (this.name === 'send') {                     
            console.log(send());
            return;
        }           

    });
});
function connect() {
    if (socket !== null)
        return;
    socket = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:8000/');

    socket.onopen = function() {
        console.log('open');
    };

    socket.onmessage = function(e) {
        var el = $('#output');
        var m = JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(e.data)).message;
        el.val(m + '\n' + el.val());
    };

    socket.onclose = function(e) {
        // e.reason ==> total.js client.close('reason message');
        console.log('close');
    };
}

function send() {
    var el = $('input[name="message"]');
    var msg = el.val();

    if (socket !== null && msg.length > 0)
        socket.send(encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify({ message: msg })));

    el.val('');
    return msg;
}
```

This is my `default.js`

```
 exports.install = function(framework) {
 framework.route('/', view_homepage);
 framework.route('/usage/', view_usage);
 framework.websocket('/', socket_homepage, ['json']);

 };

 function view_usage() {
 var self = this;
 self.plain(self.framework.usage(true));
 }

function view_homepage() {
var self = this;
self.view('homepage');
}
function socket_homepage() {
    var controller = this;
    controller.on('open', function(client) {
    console.log('Connect');    
});

controller.on('message', function(client, message) {
    console.log(message);
 /*
 var self = this;
 var message = MODEL('message').schema;
 var model = self.body;
 var message = new message({ message: model.message }).save(function(err) {
    if (err)
        self.throw500(err);

    // Read all messages
    message.find(self.callback());
});   
*/      
});
controller.on('error', function(error, client) {
    framework.error(error, 'websocket', controller.uri);
});
}
```

Any help Please!!!

[This is complete project](https://github.com/samd90/websocket.git)

---Update---

In this function i use to save data to MongoDB
but it didn't give any error.also Didnt save the data to database.i not sure my code is write or wrong

```
  controller.on('message', function(client, message) {
    console.log(message);
 /*
 var self = this;
 var message = MODEL('message').schema;
 var model = self.body;
 var message = new message({ message: model.message }).save(function(err) {
    if (err)
        self.throw500(err);

    // Read all messages
    message.find(self.callback());
});   
*/      
});
```

This my mongoose.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://totaldemo:123456@ds029979.mongolab.com:29979/totaldemo');
global.mongoose = mongoose;
```

This is my user.js

```
 var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({ user: String})
 exports.schema = mongoose.model('user', userSchema,'user');
 exports.name = 'user';
```

Comment: Use mongoose or the node-monogodb-native driver. Where is the code with which you tried to connect to mongodb. What did not work?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know totaljs framework at all, but i see some issues already with plain javascript.

First of all, i suggest You set up Your model like this:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var userSchema = new Schema({
  user: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

and then in controller, when You import:

```
var User = require('path/to/user/file')
```

You can use it like this straight away:

```
User.find()
```

Also - i totally dont get what are You doing later.
You defined `user` model and exported NOTHING MORE than a STRING. Only tthing it will do is, that when You import that user to variable `User`, the `User.name` will === to `'user`' string. so in Your example it would be:

```
var User = require('path/to/user/model/file')
console.log(User.name) // prints 'user'
```

and nothing more! There are no models attached to that export. Maybe its how totaljs works, but i VERY doubt it.

Later on - You try to ... use message model. Where it comes from? You defined user model, not message model.

Another thing - as i stated - i dont know totaljs, but I doubt it ask YOu to define `var model`, and then never use variable `model`.

I strongly suggest using plain node with mongoose first, then try to integrate it with any fullstack.

For sure its not a solution, but maybe it points out some problems in Your code and will help.

**EDIT:**

I looked quickly in totaljs, and it looks that You really should export string (which is little weird and doing magic stuff:) ), but its NOT mongoose, and i guess will ONLY work with native totaljs model solution. You cant use mongoose and totaljs like that. I dont know how much not using native totaljs models system ruins framework other options, but its probably safer to use native one.

Honestly, i dont have time to look deeper into docs, but google says nothing about sql or even mongo inside of totaljs docs... so, You have to figure it out :)

**EDIT2** i found https://github.com/totaljs/examples/tree/master/mongoose and it looks weird... check if that example works (looks like You seen it, Your code is similar :)). check if You're mongod is working, check if You can conenct from plain node...

*Honestly sorry, i surrender. Totaljs has to much magic and abstraction for me to help You out with this :(. Hope You will find Your answer.*

Comment: Thank you for helping..yes i seen total.js mongoose answer and it work fine with plane node.but i cannot connect websocket with it..yes you are right google says nothing about it :(